# Check if a certain group of checkboxes is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a total of ten checkboxes on my page, the last five of them are special. And if anyone of them are checked a want to show a message on the page that extra costs will apply to those products. They all have different name and value. Since I can't have the same id on all the checkboxes I am really stuck.

This was the last thing I tested but I cant get to work for all 5 checkboxes.

```
var check;
$("#test-with-is").on("click", function(){
    check = $("#mycheckbox").is(":checked");
    if(check) {
        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else {
        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
});
```

Any clue what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class to your special checkbox, and check by it's property "checked".

```js
$(".special").on("click", function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked')){
        alert("Checkbox is checked.");
    } else {
        alert("Checkbox is unchecked.");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="special">
<input type="checkbox" class="special">
<input type="checkbox" class="special">
<input type="checkbox" class="special">
<input type="checkbox" class="special">
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Andy (and all the others that answered).

Answer (score 2):

Use a common class

```
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" />
<input type="checkbox" class="last_five" />
<input type="checkbox" class="last_five" />
<input type="checkbox" class="last_five" />
<input type="checkbox" class="last_five" />
```

and check if any of them are checked

```
$("#test-with-is").on("click", function(){
    if ( $(".last_five").is(":checked") ) { // true if any are checked
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`:gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector, which is 0-based indexed, with parameter `4` , `change` event

```js
$("input:gt(4)").on("change", function() {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) alert("extra costs will apply");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<label>1<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>2<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>3<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>4<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>5<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>6<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>7<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>8<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>9<input type="checkbox"></label>
<label>10<input type="checkbox"></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

add a class to your special checkboxes

```
class='special_checkbox'
```

now you can check if anyone of them is checked or not like this

```
if($('.special_checkbox:checked').length() > 0){
 // checked 
}
```